# How to install NewRelic on Plesk server, so it would automatically divide different domains into different apps?

Tags: linux

I have a dedicated server, which hosts 30+ domains. I use Plesk 11 for hosting management, also user creation, databases etc. I would like to see NewRelic Lite reports per domain, and I think it is possible to do that on Lite account which is free. At the same time, hey provide free Server monitoring, which is way superior then similar products I have tried out.

At the moment, when installing NewRelic, it joins its report for all domains on the server. This is not a desired behavior, but I do not seem able to change this via .htaccess files in domain directories. Is there some system variable in Plesk, that would allow me to use the same config file to divide whole server report into domains as apps?

Knowing the popularity of both solutions, it is hard to imagine that somebody would not have cracked this already.

Comment: Maybe try Stackoverflow SE for more answers?

Comment: @mdpc What on earth would this have to do with SO?

Comment: This seemed the most relevant site.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from new relic docs, you need to add following directive to php5_module section for each of apache's virtual host:

```
php_value newrelic.appname "$VAR->domain->idnName"
```

You can do it via [customization of domain's virtual hosting template](https://newrelic.com/docs/php/per-directory-settings#perdir-apache):

1. `mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain`
2. `cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/domainVirtualHost.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/`
3. add or change what you need in `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/domainVirtualHost.php`
4. to apply new configuration for all domains: `/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all`

Check also [this page](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/68693.htm)

Comment: You are right. I am also looking for the way to detect Wordpress and Drupal based on the Plesk native package installer (It allows to install Wordpress and Drupal from the backend). BTW, correct Syntax to include in domainVirtualHost.php is : <IfModule mod_php5.c> php_value newrelic.appname "<?php echo $VAR->domain->idnName ?>"
</IfModule>

Comment: For installing application in Plesk from the backend you can try API-RPC call http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/64508.htm

Comment: This has been useful too: http://blogs.reliablepenguin.com/2015/02/11/plesk-new-relic

Comment: Also to point out that the above does not seem to work with Plesk Onyx (17) with php7-fpm.